# SQL Server query to find last occurred number greater than 0. If there is no number greater than 0 then query should return 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data like below.

Case A:

```
Amount (column name)
------
0
0
450
890
0
0
```

Case B:

```
Amount (column name)
------
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

- In case 'A', query should return 890
- In case 'B' query should return 0

I am looking for a SQL Server query which returns the expected results.

Comment: "Last" has no meaning if you don't specify an order

Comment: There is no "natural" order of the rows in the table. Just because you have presented them in a particular order above doesn't mean that SQL Server will use that order - without an additional column that can be used that specifies row order

Comment: Adding to the comment by @HoneyBadger , a relational database table is an unordered set of rows so you need to superimpose ordering to determine first or last. Perhaps you want `MAX(Amount)`, to get the highest value in the table?

Comment: Your description doesn't match your title. You say "last" value, but then your description says query "A" should return `890`. `890` is the 4th row down, and the "last" (in order of them being listed) is `0`. it should be `0` for both is it was the "last". It seems you want `MAX`.

Comment: @Larnu, last *positive* value, `0` is not generally considered positive (though not everybody agrees on that)

Comment: yeah - so then there is an implied "if there was no last positive value return zero anyway"? Or  "if there was no last positive value return the highest one anyway"? "if there was no last positive value return the last one anyway"?

Comment: From the desired results for B apparently not. This only consists of `0` and therefore has no positive numbers under that definition but is desired to return `0`

Comment: If `0` isn't positive (according to the OP), then there should be no results for the second query, or is should return `NULL`, though @HoneyBadger  . The requirements conflict.

Comment: @Larnu, I think everybody will agree this wasn't the best formulated question, but at least they found their solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an ordering, the simplest method might be:

```
select coalesce(max(amount), 0)
from (select top (1) amount
      from t
      where amount > 0
      order by <ordering column> desc
     ) t;
```